# Scraping JSON from AJAX calls

Tags: python, json, ajax, networking, web-scraping

#### Background

Considering this url:

`base_url = "https://www.olx.bg/ad/sobstvenik-tristaen-kamenitsa-1-CID368-ID81i3H.html"`

I want to make the ajax call for the telephone number:

`ajax_url = "https://www.olx.bg/ajax/misc/contact/phone/7XarI/?pt=e3375d9a134f05bbef9e4ad4f2f6d2f3ad704a55f7955c8e3193a1acde6ca02197caf76ffb56977ce61976790a940332147d11808f5f8d9271015c318a9ae729"`

#### Wanted results

If I press the button through the site in my chrome browser in the console I would **get the wanted result**:

```
{"value":"088 *****"}
```

#### debugging

If I open a new tab and paste the `ajax_url` I would always get empty values:

```
{"value":"000 000 000"}
```

If I try something like:

Bash:

`wget $ajax_url`

Python:

```
import requests


json_response= requests.get(ajax_url)
```

I would just receive the html of the the site's handling page that there is an error.

#### Ideas

I have something more when I am opening the request with the browser. What more do I have? maybe a cookie?

How do I get the wanted result with Bash/Python ?

### Edit

the code of the response html is 200

I have tried with curl I get the same html problem.

#### Kind of a fix.

I have noticed that if I copy the cookie of the browser, and make a request with all the headers INCLUDING the cookie from the browser, I get the correct result

```
# I think the most important header is the cookie
headers = DICT_WITH_HEADERS_FROM_BROWSER
json_response= requests.get(next_url,
                            headers=headers,
                            )
```

#### Final question

The only question left is how can I generate a cookie through a Python script?

Comment: Have you looked at either curl or Postman, the Chrome add on? Also this link may help https://realpython.com/python-json/

Comment: @JGFMK Curl gives me the same error html error rather than the wanted JSON output. I had checked the link you have sent me. It has good information if you have the JSON, my issue is that I can't get my hands on the JSON. I will check the rest now

Comment: Well, what kind of error is it?

Comment: @Iguananaut I will make an edit instead of returning the JSON structure, it returns me the html of the site's handler for wrong, problematic requests

Comment: "it returns me the html of the site's handler for wrong, problematic requests" you already said that. What is the *exact* error? There should also be a numeric HTTP error code. These things are meaningful.

Comment: @Iguananaut The code is 200

Comment: Not if there's an error, unless the server is misconfigured somehow. What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should create a requests Session to store cookies.
Then send a http GET request to the page that is actually calling the ajax request. If any cookie is created by the website, it is sent in GET response and your sessions stores the cookie.
Then you can easily use the session to call ajax api.

**Important Note 1:**
The ajax url you are calling in the original website is a http POST request! you should not send a get request to that url.

**Important Note 2:**
You also must extract phoneToken from the website js code which is stored in a variable like `var phoneToken = 'here is the pt';`

Sample code:

```py
import re
import requests

my_session = requests.Session()

# call html website
base_url = "https://www.olx.bg/ad/sobstvenik-tristaen-kamenitsa-1-CID368-ID81i3H.html"
base_response = my_session.get(url=base_url)
assert base_response.status_code == 200

# extract phone token from base url response
phone_token = re.findall(r'phoneToken\s=\s\'(.+)\';', base_response.text)[0]

# call ajax api
ajax_path = "/ajax/misc/contact/phone/81i3H/?pt=" + phone_token
ajax_url = "https://www.olx.bg" + ajax_path
ajax_headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'Referer': 'https://www.olx.bg/ad/sobstvenik-tristaen-kamenitsa-1-CID368-ID81i3H.html',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'
}
ajax_response = my_session.post(url=ajax_url, headers=ajax_headers)

print(ajax_response.text)
```

When you run the code above, the result below is displayed:

```
{"value":"088 558 9937"}
```

Comment: What output do u get, I get the problematic ```{"value":"000 000 000"}``` , which I receive when no cookie has been set.

Comment: @Harton this answer is completely invalid, in case if you looking for further information. let me know so i can edit my answer and post an explanation

Comment: @Harton Check my updated answer. Now the code automatically extracts phoneToken from website and prints the right result. Using selenium with webdriver works but it's not useful and takes lots of resources for such a simple web scraping.

Comment: @SinaRezaei now it's works, i removed my down-vote and upvoted for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(
    'https://www.olx.bg/ad/sobstvenik-tristaen-kamenitsa-1-CID368-ID81i3H.html')

number = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[3]/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul[1]/li[2]/div/strong").click()
time.sleep(2)
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

phone = soup.find("strong", {'class': 'xx-large'}).text

print(phone)
```

Output:

```
088 558 9937
```

Comment: Looks good but I get ```selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused```

Comment: @Harton are you able to browse the website via the browser ? if yes so please remove the following `options = Options()` and `options.add_argument('--headless')` and `options=options` and re-run the script and let me know the result.

Comment: also let me know your `OS` type

Comment: using linux, ping fails, guess I have to resolve the acces as well as the cookie issue

Comment: @Harton seems for me that you got blocked due to your multiple request.

Comment: Yes, I know, do you think there is a way to get a new session with new cookies with selenium ?